# Extending DbContext to avoid code duplication

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a project with multiple DbContext classes: one for every domain. Since EF Core isn't perfect I have some functionality I have to add to every DbContext like allowing it to handle the new JSON functionality of SQL Server 2017. There is other functionality I'm adding too but for the sake of brevity I have removed it from the example.

To add this JSON functionality to every DbContext I work with a BaseDbContext which is an abstract class that simply extends the DbContext. One of the prerequisites for the functionality is interception of SQL queries that are sent to the database. To perform this I make use of the tactic described [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/interception-in-entity-framework-core).

In the next few weeks we are moving into different development environments and I want to inject the correct connection string based on the current environment through the Options pattern. This doesn't play well with the interception tactic. Since to perform interception `GetService<DiagnosticSource>()` is called which actually triggers the OnConfiguring function BEFORE the continuation of the constructor of my SomeDbContext, which means my options are never filled in leading to a NullReferenceException.

How can I extend DbContext without triggering OnConfiguring while at the same time avoiding code duplication? I can also run a custom EF Core but I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

```
public abstract class BaseDbContext : DbContext, IBaseDbContext
{
    protected BaseDbContext()
    {
        DiagnosticListener listener = this.GetService<DiagnosticSource>() as DiagnosticListener; // This calls OnConfiguring.
        listener.SubscribeWithAdapter(new JsonInterceptor());
    }

    [DbFunction("JSON_VALUE", "")]
    public static string JsonValue(string source, string path)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    [DbFunction("TRY_CAST", "")]
    public static string TryCast(string source, string typeName)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

public class SomeDbContext : BaseDbContext, ISomeDbContext
{
    private readonly SomeDbContextOptions _options;

    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public SomeDbContext(IOptions<SomeDbContextOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        // This is called before _options is set meaning it is null in the line below.
        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer(_options.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```